# ¿Por qué me da el siguiente aviso y no se ejecuta el código?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

estoy tratando de hacer un separados de user agent string a través de ajax y php pero a la hora de hacer el code de ajax me aparece el siguiente aviso en la consola

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot access 'get_overs' before initialization ReferenceError: Cannot access 'get_overs' before initialization
> at HTMLDocument. (http://127.0.0.1/fumado/:208:19)
> at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
> at t (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined

Ajax:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
const get_overs = <?php $get_over = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];?>
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "./assets/php/locate.php",
data: { get_over: get_overs }
}).done(function( msg ) {
console.log( "Los datos que se recibieron: " + msg );
});
});

</script>
```

Php (inicio de pág):

```
   <?php
$get_over = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


?>
```

locate.php:

```
<?php 
$get_over = $_POST['get_overs'];


$separar = explode("Mozilla/5.0",$get_over);
$allow = array("Windows"); //dominios válidos
$dom = $separar[1];

if(in_array($dom,$allow)){
   print 'allowed';
}else{

print 'wtf';

}
?>
```

Comment: creo que es mala idea mesclar ajax con php en el mismo archivo ... puedes validar que contiene la constante: get_overs ???

Comment: No tiene nada que ver ajax en el mismo archivo... es esta linea `const get_overs = <?php $get_over = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];?>`

Comment: ¿Por que hay una asignacion dentro de otra asignacion?

Comment: Porque me gustaría que la variable javascript obtuviera el dato de la variable de php

Comment: Si pero primero debe ocurrir la asignacion en php para que la puedas pasar a otro lado, no una dentro de otra.

Comment: Tengo  en el inicio de la página este código "$get_over = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];" que es el que le da el valor a la variable

Comment: Entonces por favor corrige el codigo, por que yo veo una linea con un graso error acá.

Comment: PHP ocurre en el sirvador antes de enviar la página al cliente, pero $(document).ready() ocurre en el cliente despues de toda la página está enviada y está lista para procesar.

Answer (score 0):

Como no estás enviando una salida con `<?php $get_over = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];?>`, el navegador recibe lo siguiente:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    const get_overs = 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./assets/php/locate.php",
        data: { get_over: get_overs }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        console.log( "Los datos que se recibieron: " + msg );
    });
});
</script>
```

En resumen, estás asignando la petición AJAX a la constante `get_overs` y, por lo tanto, no puedes usarla dentro.

En todo caso, sabiendo que ya definiste `$get_over`, deberías hacer un echo de la variable y, como se trata de una cadena, encerrar entre comillas, por ejemplo:

```
const get_overs = '<?php echo $get_over; ?>';
```

Esto resuelve el problema de que no puedes usar la constante antes de definirla, pero me queda la duda de porqué hacer que PHP detecte el navegador y pasarlo a Javascript, cuando puedes hacerlo directamente con [navigator.userAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent) y, además, ¿cuál es la necesidad de enviar nuevamente el dato al servidor?

Comment: Te explico, lo que quiero es conseguir de forma continua el string del user agent para  mediante un código de php separar un string sin parsear, en este caso, "Mozilla 5.0" para detectar  por ejemplo a una empresa, por ejemplo Facebook que siempre suele incluir la partícula "facebook" en el string. Es todo más por organización que por otra cosa ya que ese "log" lo mostraré en un panel interno.

Comment: Con ajax lo que quiero es que cada x segundos se actualice el code para registrar el tiempo del usuario en mi web, así podría detectar crawlers y diferenciar entre usuario  legítimo, usuario interesado y usuario malicioso; claro está que el code de ajax aún no lo tengo completo, esto del user agent es una prueba me queda por desarrollar todo lo demás